# How do i get latest post by category?

Tags: php, wordpress

currently i am stuck with the problem .my code is

```
$category_ids = get_all_category_ids();

    foreach($category_ids as $kk=> $cat_id) {

      $cat_name= query_posts( 'posts_per_page=1&orderby=date&order=ASC&cat='.$cat_id);

    if (have_posts ()) :while(have_posts()):the_post
```

this is the code i write in my loop.php file what i want is to take only latest post by category showing only 1 post of each category by date

Comment: So what is the actual problem? The 'posts_per_page' parameter is used to determine the amount of posts per page so it should display the only one latest post by date...

Comment: but i have not been able see my remaining posts, how can i ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a plugin like [this](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/latest-post-from-each-category-plugin-for-wordpress/) and find out how it is done.
Also, [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/latest-post-per-category-from-category-1-8-on-homepage) thread has something that may help you. It contains a snippet that shows the last post in each of a list of categories. Wold post the code, but it craps up the formatting, sorry.